# Order of integration resolves "Indeterminate expression encountered."

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

Today I came across the following integral:

```
Integrate[(
Sqrt[2] E^(-x^2 - y^2) y)/\[Pi], 
{y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

and mathematica evaluates it as zero (which it should be due to parity). But if I exchange the order of integration I get

```
Integrate[(
Sqrt[2] E^(-x^2 - y^2) y)/\[Pi], 
{x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

a warning about "Indeterminate expression encountered." And I have no idea why. Integrating x and y separately gives

```
Integrate[(Sqrt[2] E^(-x^2 - y^2) y)/\[Pi], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
>> E^-y^2 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] y
Integrate[E^-y^2 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] y, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
>> 0
```

Why is MMA complaining if I write it as a 2D integration? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Both ways give `0` without complaint in V10.0.1.

Comment: ui, then I will upgrade immediately. My version is 10.0.0, thanks

Comment: Fails in 10.0.0 for me, too.  Works in 9.0.1.